# How to start a bundle on boot in apache karaf

Tags: osgi, activemq-classic, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I want to start Camel and ActiveMQ during boot when I start karaf, What i've found is the etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg which lists features that should be started during boot.

```
featuresBoot=config,ssh,management,camel,activemq,camel-jms,activemq-spring,activemq-camel
```

This works fine for all but 'activemq-camel' (fair enough, since it's not a feature).
To get the apache-camel bundle installed i've to run run the command:

```
karaf@...>osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-camel/5.5.0
```

It works, but I'd rather just get it running at boot time.
Can I somehow get the activemq-camel bundle to be installed at boot time without creating a custom feature for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apache ServiceMix has this feature already defined. To use it add `mvn:org.apache.servicemix/apache-servicemix/4.4.1/xml/features` to the `featuresRepositories` property in `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` and then `camel-activemq` to the `featuresBoot` property.

Cheers,
Jon