# How to install a bundle on boot in Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428780/how-to-start-a-bundle-on-boot-in-apache-karaf) but it doesn't quite answer my question. I am using blueprint to set up a H2 database in Karaf and it requires that I first install H2 driver and OSGi enterprise package because it contains JDBC library.

```
install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.enterprise/4.2.0
install -s mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.174
```

I added the blueprint XML file to Karaf's deploy folder and it keeps giving error messages until I install H2 and enterprise package. Ideally, I would like to install both enterprise and H2 before the blueprint script kicks in, so I am thinking somehow add it to karaf's boot process but I am not sure how.

Any insights will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to hot deploy a features XML before deploying your bundle.

See the Karaf [deployer](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/deployer.html#Featuresdeployer) guide for more details. Here is an XML example:

```
<features>
  <feature name="features_test">
    <bundle>mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.enterprise/4.2.0</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.174</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

Comment: Ah ok, so I would just drop that xml file in deploy folder? Couldn't I just add my blueprint to it also? I need to be able to sequence them, first enterprise, then h2, then h2 db.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to publish the blueprint file to the maven repo. This way you can reference it in feature files. See the maven build helper plugin with goal attach artifacts. Many feature files are deployed tnis way.
You can also put your blueprint file into an ordinary bundle. Then it will also work in other containers than karaf.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Also, I tried putting my blueprint file in my bundle but it doesn't seem to load, I couldn't get access to it in the bundle activation start method, any thoughts?

Comment: If you use a blueprint file then you should not use an activaor. What exactly did you try to do in the activator of the blueprint bundle?

Comment: I am following your Karaf database access tutorial http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access In the activator start method, I am getting the JNDI datasource value specified in the blueprint file for the H2 database.

Comment: Ah ok .. so you a are using blueprint for the datasource and an activator in another bundle. That should be fine. Perhaps you accees the service before it is published. Do you use a servicetracker? That should help.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, thanks for the suggestion but I'm unfamiliar with servicetracker, I'll have to check it out. Also, I just upgraded to Karaf 3.0.0 and ran into an error, I was using 3.0.0-RC1, http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Karaf-3-0-0-Problem-writing-resource-org-h2-Driver-class-td4030880.html I would appreciate your feedback there. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Is there a good blueprint tutorial? I am new to it and getting the sense that I am not quite doing it the right way, ideally, I like to load the H2 database via blueprint in my bundle instead of outside of it.

Comment: Not really. There is the apache aries page about blueprint and of course the spec at the OSGi alliance. One good place to start is to look into the blueprint files from Apache Karaf. You will find a lot of use cases there.